# WSO2 ESB - Payload not return on response

Tags: java, sequence, apache-synapse, wso2-esb

I'm exposed a simple Inbound Endpoint with a filter. In the first switch a try but my payload not on the response.

Second switch with a fault the correct response (payload) are send in the response.

**How my payload can be send on request response ?**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence name="authUser" trace="disable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <property name="senha" scope="default" type="STRING" value="ah"/>
    <log level="full">
        <property expression="get-property('REQUEST_PAYLOAD')" name="Request Payload"/>
        <property name="Text" value="Recebi o request"/>
        <property expression="get-property('senha')" name="senha"/>
        <property expression="/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/MT_OrdemServico_Dealer_v2/ORDEMSERVICO/ID_CHASSI" name="ID_CHASSI" xmlns:ser="http://teste.com.br/h3s/4W/servico/" xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"/>
        <property expression="/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Header/ser:User/Senha" name="RequestSenha" xmlns:ser="http://teste.com.br/h3s/4W/servico/" xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"/>
    </log>
    <filter description="CheckIfPasswordIsCorrect" xmlns:ser="http://teste.com.br/h3s/4W/servico/" xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xpath="get-property('senha') = string(/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Header/ser:User/Senha)">
        <then>
            <log description="Log Flow" level="full">
                <property name="senha" value="correta"/>
            </log>
            <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="text/plain"/>
            <enrich>
                <source clone="true" type="inline">
                    <soapenv:Envelope>
                        <soapenv:Header/>
                        <soapenv:Body>
                            <text xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/commons/ns/payload"/>
                        </soapenv:Body>
                    </soapenv:Envelope>
                </source>
                <target type="envelope"/>
            </enrich>
            <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="text/xml"/>
            <property action="remove" name="NO_ENTITY_BODY" scope="axis2"/>
            <header action="remove" name="To" scope="default"/>
            <property name="RESPONSE" scope="default" type="STRING" value="true"/>
        </then>
        <else>
            <log level="custom">
                <property name="senha" value="errada"/>
            </log>
            <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
                <format>
                    <SOAP:Envelope xmlns:SOAP="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema-instance">
                        <SOAP:Header/>
                        <SOAP:Body/>
                    </SOAP:Envelope>
                </format>
                <args/>
            </payloadFactory>
            <makefault version="soap11">
                <code value="soap11Env:Client" xmlns:soap11Env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/>
                <reason value="Usuário não encontrado"/>
            </makefault>
        </else>
    </filter>
    <respond/>
</sequence>
```

[image: Payload on the end of sequence]

Comment: Could you try to log the envelope end of filter-then case?

Comment: why dont you use the payload factory mediator ,instead of using enrich to construct the message body?